# Access only table data in Orientdb using Codeigniter-PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am getting data as follows ::[Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIkhM.png)

```
$client = new OrientDB('localhost', 2424); 
$client->connect('root', 'root'); 
$client->DBOpen('krshop', 'root', 'root'); 
$data = $client->select('select from users limit 10'); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Comment: The code which i am executing is as follows :
$client = new OrientDB('localhost', 2424);
$client->connect('root', 'root');
$client->DBOpen('krshop', 'root', 'root');
$data = $client->select('select from users limit 10');
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);

Comment: So what is your question??? can you explain in more and more ??

Comment: @SachinKumar Please put the additional informations in your question!

Comment: I want only user_id, username, mobile etc. from users collection only i.e I want data of content index only.